# call a new function without closing the file

Tags: python, iterator, yield

I have a method that opens a csv file and another method that I want to use to process this file -but I also need it to process different types of objects, so I want to keep it as an independent method.

```
import csv

class Loader():

    def load_from_csv(self, csv_path: str):

        with open(csv_path, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            reader = csv.DictReader(file)
            return self._read_and_yield(reader)
    
    @classmethod
    def _read_and_yield(cls,reader):
        for row in reader:
            yield(row)

loader = Loader()
for row in loader.load_from_csv('sample.csv'):
    print(row)
```

But I get `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`, because the file seems to get closed when I call the `_read_and_yield` method. Here it just yields the rows, but imagine a case in which I have to do more operations: I should repeat this process for each type of file (namely `read_from_excel`).

How should I handle this?

Comment: If `_read_and_yield()` is a classmethod, why is `self` the first parameter?

Comment: Sorry, my bad (I edited the question). That doesn't seem to be the problem anyway.

Comment: The `with` block in `load_from_csv()` closes the file, before the caller has any chance to iterate the returned generator.  One possible fix would be to make `load_from_csv()` itself be the generator - the loop with `yield`s would be *inside* the `with`, so the file doesn't get closed until you've iterated through the entire file.

Comment: It doesn't get closed when you call `_read_and_yield`.  It gets closed when you execute the `return` statement, which exits the `with` block.  If you don't want it to automatically close the file when you return, then don't use `with`.  Just call `open`.  But then at some point you should call `close` to close it.

Comment: it is more a `@staticmethod` than a `@classmethod`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider rewriting your Loader class as a context manager.

Something like this:

```
from csv import DictReader

class Loader:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._filename = filename
    def __enter__(self):
        self._fd = open(self._filename, "r", encoding="utf-8", newline="")
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *_):
        self._fd.close() #type: ignore
    def row(self):
        yield from DictReader(self._fd) #type: ignore

with Loader("foo.csv") as loader:
    for r in loader.row():
        print(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `with` block closes the file when the enclosing function returns so `csv.DictReader` iterator can no longer read from the file.

You can instead make `load_from_csv` yield the generated values from `_read_and_yield` in the context manager so that the file handle can remain open while the caller iterates with it:

```
with open(csv_path, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    yield from self._read_and_yield(reader)
```